# Javascript Regex Problems : Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

```
replacedStr = replacedStr.replace(/&^*/g, "asdfasdf");
```

I need replace all with this regular expression:

```
/&^*/g
```

But it doesn't work, I can see the error messages **Nothing to repeat** in Chrome.

What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: what's your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The *"nothing to repeat"* error comes from improper escaping of metacharacters. Both `^` and `*` are consider special characters meaning the beginning of string anchor and `*` is a repetition operator. To literally match these characters, you need to properly escape them.

```
/&\^\*/g
```

If you're looking to replace **those** characters anywhere, consider using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
/[&^*]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` is a special meta charcater in regex which matches the start of the line  boundary. In-order to match a literal `^` symbol, you need to escape `^` symbol in your regex.

I think you're trying to achieve something like in the below.

```
> 'foo&^*'.replace(/&\^\*/g, "asdfasdf")
'fooasdfasdf'
> 'foo&^^'.replace(/&\^*/g, "asdfasdf")
'fooasdfasdf'
```